# velocity controller question: updated

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a better way to adjust for gravity then adjusting min velocity. I thought PID would control torque to over come gravity but how? Any ideas on how to do this?

update1:
I was able to PID and inertia values in the urdf and now I am getting better results. Though I am not sure how to adjust PID values so that lower velocities are favored. Since velocities can sometimes be below threshold needed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81041/velocity-controller-question:-updated/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-19**:
What is your question?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-19**:
I updated the question to be more direct.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-20**:
Please stop rewriting the question from scratch every time. It is not a whiteboard to wipe it. Just ADD more details below the original text with the line "EDIT" showing where additional info starts. Otherwise it makes almost impossible for people to track the history of your problem.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-21**:
sorry. Sometimes my understanding of the problem changes so much. Should I just keep updating as you suggest. Or would it be better to close it and open a new one. Or would either be more acceptable.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-21**:
In general, one problem - one question. If you have tried a solution suggested by someone, but there are still issues, then add new info to original question showing what you have tried and what was the result. In case you have questions regarding given answer, then add comments to it (as you did). Once the problem is solved mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-21**:
If a new question arises from your original one (i.e. not more specific details), then leave the original one open and just open a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to PID and inertia values in the urdf and now I am getting better results. Though I am not sure how to adjust PID values so that lower velocities are favored. Since  velocities can sometimes be below threshold needed.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-09-22**:
Please don't add comments as answers.